# How to use stream bridge to send messages to multiple kafka cluster

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

We are consuming messages from multiple kafka cluster.

How to send messages to different cluster using stream bridge and we have dynamic destinations i.e. destination config cannot be defined in yaml.

Env details

spring boot : 3.1.1
spring-cloud.version : 2022.0.3

had gone through below sample as well

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/main/multi-binder-samples/multi-binder-two-kafka-clusters

In the example destination is explicitly defined and used stream bridge to send messages.

In our case, destination is dynamic hence its not possible to define it in yaml.

Below exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A default binder has been requested, but there is more than one binder available for 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.messaging.DirectWithAttributesChannel' : kafka2,kafka1, and no default binder has been set.
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.doGetBinderConventional(DefaultBinderFactory.java:240) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.doGetBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:163) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.DefaultBinderFactory.getBinder(DefaultBinderFactory.java:153) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.getBinder(BindingService.java:412) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.BindingService.bindProducer(BindingService.java:278) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.resolveDestination(StreamBridge.java:252) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.send(StreamBridge.java:156) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.send(StreamBridge.java:144) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge.send(StreamBridge.java:140) ~[spring-cloud-stream-4.0.1.jar:4.0.1]
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/2114

There is a binderName in streambridge.send method with which we can explicitly pass configured binder.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).